# union a column in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I have a dictionary database.
it has 3 columns.

```
ID , word ,meaning
```

- 1  =   landscape  =  meaning1
- 2  =   landscape   = meaning2
- 3   =  landscape   = meaning3
- 4  =   landscape  =  meaning4
- 5  =   landscape   = meaning5
- 6  =   glossy  =     mean1
- 7  =   glossy  =     mean2
- 8   =  glossy   =    mean3
- 9  =   glossy   =    mean4

How can i union the meanings of the words like this:

- 1   =  landscape =   meaning1,meaning2,meaning3,meaning4,meaning5
- 2   =  landscape =   mean1,mean2,mean3,mean4

Comment: Did you mean :
2     glossy    mean1,mean2,mean3,mean4

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access? The answer won't be the same.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: thanx for your helps.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT does not work on ms access

Comment: Easy to find msaccess alternative  http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html (though not easy to implement I guess) or google msaccess group_concat

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY` it as

```
SELECT id, word, GROUP_CONCAT(meaning ORDER BY meaning)
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY word
```

For large number of values, `GROUP_CONCAT` will truncate the values from the end. To handle this, set `group concat max len` before executing your query

```
SET SESSION GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT
    word,
    GROUP_CONCAT(meaning ORDER BY meaning)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
     word;
```

[image]

### Demo